# phantomjs does not capture karma because socket.io.js is not found

Tags: socket.io, npm, phantomjs, karma-runner

I use phantomjs 1.9.16.

When I run my unit tests with karma runnter I am asked to:

"To capture a browser open http://localhost:9999/tests/"

I do this in my WebStorm 10 IDE and click on the above message to open the default browser.

"Karma - starting" appears then in the browser viewport.

Karma-Server Tab in the WebStrom IDE has this output:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\node.exe" "C:\Program Files (x86)\JetBrains\WebStorm 10.0.1\plugins\js-karma\js_reporter\karma-intellij\lib\intellijServer.js" --karmaPackageDir=C:\MyApp\node_modules\karma --configFile=C:\MyApp\test\karma.conf.js
INFO [karma]: Karma v0.12.32 server started at http://localhost:9999/tests/
INFO [launcher]: Starting browser PhantomJS
WARN [web-server]: 404: /tests/socket.io/socket.io.js
WARN [web-server]: 404: /tests/socket.io/socket.io.js
WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (1/2).
WARN [web-server]: 404: /tests/socket.io/socket.io.js
WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
INFO [launcher]: Trying to start PhantomJS again (2/2).
WARN [web-server]: 404: /tests/socket.io/socket.io.js
WARN [launcher]: PhantomJS have not captured in 60000 ms, killing.
ERROR [launcher]: PhantomJS failed 2 times (timeout). Giving up.
```

Is the problem with karma or phantomjs?

Actually it looks to me that => WARN [web-server]: 404: /tests/socket.io/socket.io.js

socket.io.js is not found when I check the source code of the html page under view-source:http://localhost:9999/tests/

Comment: hey, I have exactly the same error right now. have you figured out the issue?

Comment: Yes by putting my old project in a new environment with GULP!

Comment: I fixed mine by removing "node_modules/" and running $ npm install

Comment: same error on TFS Build Server, local works fine.